# Campo SELECT HTML exibindo Mês anterior, atual e próximo apenas

Tags: php, html, data

Estou precisando fazer com que o campo SELECT que hoje está assim (código abaixo) exibia apenas os mês anterior, atual e próximo. Por exemplo: Como estamos no mês de MAIO então irá exibir nesse select (html) apenas os meses de ABRIL MAIO e JUNHO e conforme avançar meses exibira MAIO, JUNHO e JULHO....

Estou pegando sistema pronto para modificar aqui no estágio o que eu tenho atualmente de código é isso:

```
<select class="form-control" style="width: 200px;" name="Mes" id="Mes" onblur="verificaDataBaixaBoleto();">
                                <?php

                                $y = date('n'); // Mês 1 a 12

                                    if($this->mes){
                                        $mesatual = $this->mes;
                                    }
                                    for($x=1;$x<=12;$x++){
                                        $mes = $x;
                                        echo "<option";
                                        if($x == $mesatual){
                                            echo " selected='selected'";
                                        }
                                        echo " value='";
                                        echo $mes;
                                        echo "'>";

                                        if($x == 1){
                                            echo "Janeiro";
                                        }
                                        if($x == 2){
                                            echo "Fevereiro";
                                        }
                                        if($x == 3){
                                            echo "Março";
                                        }
                                        if($x == 4){
                                            echo "Abril";
                                        }
                                        if($x == 5){
                                            echo "Maio";
                                        }
                                        if($x == 6){
                                            echo "Junho";
                                        }
                                        if($x == 7){
                                            echo "Julho";
                                        }
                                        if($x == 8){
                                            echo "Agosto";
                                        }
                                        if($x == 9){
                                            echo "Setembro";
                                        }
                                        if($x == 10){
                                            echo "Outubro";
                                        }
                                        if($x == 11){
                                            echo "Novembro";
                                        }
                                        if($x == 12){
                                            echo "Dezembro";
                                        }

                                        echo "</option>";

                                    }
                                ?>
                        </select>
```

Estava tentando fazer alguma comparação para que fosse possível exibir, só que acho que me perdi na lógica.

Comment: Busca o mês de hoje em números, cria duas váriaveis mesAnterior e mesSucessor, coloca o valor delas como mesAtual -1 e mesAtual+1, faz um método que transcreva o mes de números para texto, vualá

Comment: Entendi, mas nada que consiga aproveitar esse código de cima? Já estava criando o  $y = date('n'); // Mês 1 a 12 para ver...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vê se esse código te ajuda :)

```
//FUNCAO PARA ESCREVER MES POR EXTENSO
function mesExtenso($mes){
    if($mes == '01'){echo 'JANEIRO';}
    if($mes == '02'){echo 'FEVEREIRO';}
    if($mes == '03'){echo 'MARCO';}
    if($mes == '04'){echo 'ABRIL';}
    if($mes == '05'){echo 'MAIO';}
    if($mes == '06'){echo 'JUNHO';}
    if($mes == '07'){echo 'JULHO';}
    if($mes == '08'){echo 'AGOSTO';}
    if($mes == '09'){echo 'SETEMBRO';}
    if($mes == '10'){echo 'OUTUBRO';}
    if($mes == '11'){echo 'NOVEMBRO';}
    if($mes == '12'){echo 'DEZEMBRO';}
    echo "<br>";
}

//VERIFICANDO MES PASSADO
$mes_passado = new DateTime();
$mes_passado->modify('-1 months');
mesExtenso($mes_passado->format('m'));

//VERIFICANDO MES ATUAL
$mes_atual = new DateTime();
mesExtenso($mes_atual->format('m'));

//VERIFICANDO PROXIMO MES
$mes_futuro = new DateTime();
$mes_futuro->modify('+1 months');
mesExtenso($mes_futuro->format('m'));
```

Como estamos em Maio, esse código retorna:

```
ABRIL
MAIO
JUNHO
```

Comment: E como é que eu pego o valor em número mesmo? Pois tem que entrar no <option> o valor numerico para mandar para banco. =\

Comment: Onde aparece `$mes_passado->format('m')` ele está com o numero do mês, que é onde eu passo para a função retornar o mês em extenso.

Comment: Muito bom, parece que agora deu tudo certo, obrigado cara!

Answer (score 0):

Para exibir apenas os três meses(anterior, atual e seguinte), pode criar um array com range() que começa com o valor do mês atual menos um e vai até o mês atual mais dois, para já imprimir o mês por extenso use o locale e strftime() em conjunto.

[exemplo - ideone](http://ideone.com/YXCUN9).